Identifying Permutations Yielding a Specific Kendall Tau Correlation with an Original Series
I am currently engaged in a project that entails the analysis of ordinal data, focusing specifically on determining the rank correlation between various permutations of a dataset and an original series of numbers. This original series is a sequence of ranks, let us say from 1 to 8. The core of my inquiry is to uncover all feasible permutations of this series that, upon comparison with the original series, exhibit a predetermined Kendall tau correlation coefficient.
To elucidate, the Kendall tau correlation coefficient is a statistical measure employed to assess the ordinal association between two quantified variables. For my research, it is crucial to identify permutations that align with a specific correlation value when juxtaposed with the original series. This endeavour underpins my theoretical investigation into rank-size laws and their implications.
I seek guidance on a methodology or algorithm capable of generating permutations of the series that achieve the specified Kendall tau correlation efficiently. A solution that can be executed in Python, taking advantage of libraries such as NumPy or SciPy, would be ideal given their comprehensive capabilities for statistical and numerical analysis. But one must be careful with memory and computational demand!
For instance, if the original series is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] and the target Kendall tau correlation is 0.5, how would one proceed to generate all permutations that, when compared with the original series, result in this specific correlation coefficient? How to deal with memory if the dataset goes from 1 to 20 for example?
Any advice on tackling this issue, including pertinent code examples or references to scholarly articles, would be immensely valuable.
